vc-relax calculation on two-dimensional slab
Is performing only a relaxation calculation (calculation='relax') sufficient for geometrical optimization in conducting a density functional theory (DFT) study of 2D slabs, such as in the case of a $2×2×1$ monolayer of $\mathrm{MoS}_2?$, or should I perform variable cell relaxation (calculation='vc-relax')  too?

Ideally, you would want the x and y cell parameters to change (assuming the 2d material is in the XY plane), whilst the z cell parameter is kept fixed to prevent interaction between the slabs.
This freezing of the z cell parameter could be done by using:
calculation='vc-relax'

along with the CELL block
&CELL
cell_dofree = 'c'
/

As mentioned here under the cell_dofree tag

thank you @Atom

@Atom How to choose between "2Dxy" and "c"? Also, any idea on VASP related tag? I tried using "LATTICE_CONSTRAINTS = .TRUE. .TRUE. .FALSE.", but the z-axis parameter still changed.
